# "How does an immaterial activity (eg thinking a thought) inform a material medium (eg the brain) in which it is manifested?"

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, dualism

I do not think this question can be answered adequately unless the thinker takes a 'moral realist' (moral reality) position - defined as a reality independent of the Mind.

A Thought is an "immaterial activity" in an immaterial reality.

If so, how does a thought (in an immaterial reality independent of Mind) inform the Brain (a material medium dependent on Mind).

But there is, as you probably have guessed, a deeper problem involved:

The Body-Mind Problem - or, more accurately in my view, The Body-Mind-Soul Problem

So, in addition to taking a moral realist position, the thinker must also take a position regarding either the Dualism of Body and Mind, or the Dualism of Body and Soul.

But whatever position is taken - Body/Mind or Body/Soul - my question remains : How does an immaterial activity (eg thinking a thought) inform a material medium (eg the brain).

Common-sense suggests a thought (eg of lifting the arm) informs the brain (the arm lifts). But how does it do this?

Comment: This is a good philosophy question, but not a good stack exchange question, because it has no well-defined, uncontroversial answer.

Comment: If the answer is well-defined and non-controversial, it is not a philosophical question.

Comment: This is not a site for philosophical questions *per se* it is a site for questions *about* philosophy.  You could ask this same question in relationship to a specific philosophical tradition or standpoint, and it would become answerable here.

Comment: The materialist philosopher hasn't a clue how an immaterial activity (eg thinking a thought) informs a material medium (eg the brain) in which it is manifested. Is this true?

Comment: Are you *defining* a thought to be immaterial?  If so, why would you ever expect it to "inform" a material object like the brain?  Or are you using the word "thought" in the everyday sense?  If so, where did you come up with the assertion that a thought is immaterial?

Comment: Your question, in other words, is entirely analogous to "How can a silent event, such as a shout, make a noise?".  I can't tell whether you're using a non-standard definition of "shout" or whether you're making a completely unsupported assertion about the nature of what we ordinarily call shouts.  Either way, I'm quite comfortable ignoring the question.

Comment: Ignoring the question might make you feel comfortable, but I'm more interested in your thoughts about a valid question, not your feelings of comfort.

Comment: I have defined a "thought" as immaterial because if the material brain is cut open, the thought (eg of raising my arm)(and possibly its attendant image) cannot be found...except in the form of firing neurons etc.

Comment: "why would you ever expect it [the thought] to "inform" a material object like the brain?" I "expect" nothing - it just does. Think about it - rather than ignore it.

Comment: How can thinking be regarded as immaterial? Electrochemical processes in the brain consume energy. Thinking is a physical activity.

Comment: How can an immaterial process like digestion affect the material food in your stomach?

Comment: It's true that stimulation or damage to specific areas of the brain has predictable effects of conscious thought patterns. (Does 'conscious' act as a qualifier to indicate that one might have 'unconscious' thought patterns ?) Are these effects strictly 'measurable' ? If one induces a hallucination, what can be measured in this effect ?) It also seems to be true that conscious thought patterns have predictable effects on states of the brain - the brain and central nervous system - so that e.g. the sudden sight of a ferocious animal in the vicinity will cause an increased heartbeat rate, a raise

Comment: "The brain has weight, ergo thought has weight" — Perig

Comment: http://www.the-philosopher.co.uk/reviews/darwinitis.htm

I think Tallis gives a good insight into some of the overly-grand claims made for neuroscience.

He briefly explains that the brain cannot be reduced to a computer, impressive though indeed today's computers are. 'The seemingly unlimited power of computers to do things - 'detect' events, 'calculate', 'control' outputs, [make] it superficially attractive to think of the mind-brain as a computer, and an enormously powerful one.' But the mind is non-linear and 'also unified' - computers are linear and necessarily modular - fragmented ~ MC

Comment: @RichardW.Symonds for one philosophical school of thought related, I'd see Augustine's _On The Trinity_, in which he talks about some of these relationships.

Comment: Thanks James - that's really interesting - especially with much of Augustine's work being described as Plato in Christian form: "Augustine knows by faith that God is a trinity, Father, Son and Holy Spirit, and he is seeking as far as possible to understand what he believes...
In the last eight books Augustine seeks to understand the mystery of the divine Trinity by observing an analogous trinity in the image of God, which is the human mind..." http://www.amazon.com/The-Trinity-Works-Saint-Augustine/dp/1565484460

Answer (score 6):

The question is based on a flawed premise, namely that thinking is an immaterial activity.

In fact, thinking is a product of electrochemical activity in the brain that requires energy. In fact brain activity consumes 20% of the calories burned by the body. http://www.pnas.org/content/99/16/10237.full

This [SciAm article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-does-the-brain-need-s/) quotes the same figure:

> It is well established that the brain uses more energy than any other
>   human organ, accounting for up to 20 percent of the body's total haul.

It is a fact of biology that all brain activity is a physical process taking place in the material universe, requiring energy. Cheeseburger in, philosophy out.

Therefore the premise of the question is simply incorrect as a matter of science.

ps -- I see that you commented above that you call thought "immaterial" because you can't see it. But if you cut a person open you can't see the conversion of glucose into energy or any other biochemical process. Physical entities include processes as well as solid things. You can see a rock but you can't see the strong nuclear force holding it together. That doesn't make physical processes immaterial. Perhaps you are asking how the laws of physics manage to make rocks. That's actually a pretty good question.

Comment: "all brain activity is a physical process taking place in the material universe". So the 'you' - the Self/the I - who is thinking the thought "how do the laws of physics manage to make rocks?" is the product of a physical, material process?

Comment: @RichardW.Symonds If not, where else could it live? I agree that this is an age-old philosophical question. But there is *no question* that I have thoughts in my head because biochemical processes in my body fueled certain electrochemical reactions in my brain. We can't solve the mind-body problem here today, but surely we can acknowledge the fact that thoughts are a product of physical processes in the brain. To say "The 'I' is immaterial" is to state as fact something that there is no evidence for.

Comment: Neuro-scientist John Eccles appears to confront your question "where else could it (the I) live?" by saying it lives in a non-natural order of reality, as well as a natural order of reality (the body/brain)

Comment: @RichardW.Symonds I found this article, is this what you're referring to? http://www.theosophy-nw.org/theosnw/science/prat-bra.htm Quote: *Eccles calls the fundamental neural units of the cerebral cortex dendrons, and proposes that each of the 40 million dendrons is linked with a mental unit, or psychon, representing a unitary conscious experience.* I'd say that's a stretch, but who's to say. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Yes that's it. This is part of his last book, and he excitedly put the idea forward as an answer to the age-old Mind-Body Problem.

Comment: I would agree that science leads us to accept this answer as the currently held scientific explanation for the question asked. The mind is very physical, the we know of no things which are not physical, even concepts while abstract in one sense take up very physical parts of our brain while they are thoughts in our minds. Particular areas of our brain "light up" with electrical/chemical activity when stimulated with various ideas. Thinking is simply *what it feels like* when our physical brains do what they do to process the chemicals and electrical signals (which we experience as thoughts).

Comment: When the physical brain processes chemicals and electrical signals why is it doing this? Is it because it is caused to do this by possibly other parts of the brain as byproducts of their previous neurological activity? So any experiences of 'thought' is like  meta-information or an emergent description of what 'seems' to be going on during this 'thought'. Maybe the 'immaterial' or 'non-physical' experience is really a higher-level interpretation of what is happening , and as such can this 'description can be 'used' as real usable representations for the 'thought event'.

Answer (score 2):

[A](http://exploringthemind.com/the-mind/brain-scans-can-reveal-your-decisions-7-seconds-before-you-decide) [lot](http://www.brainfacts.org/sensing-thinking-behaving/awareness-and-attention/articles/2009/decision-making/) [of](http://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2014/10/28/4115528.htm) [evidence](http://www.mrn.org/research/category/traumatic-brain-injury/) points not to conscious thought informing the brain, but the other way around.  It is well documented that [stimulation](http://www.surgicalneurologyint.com/article.asp?issn=2152-7806;year=2013;volume=4;issue=1;spage=91;epage=91;aulast=Faria)/[damage](http://www.nasponline.org/publications/cq/39/7/traumatic-brain-injury.aspx) of specific areas of the brain has measurable and predictable effects on conscious thought patterns.  This indicates to me that what we refer to as conscious thought is a byproducts of bodily functions related to these "material" portions of the brain.